# Fit a div in sibling remainging space using only flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I'm currently trying to make a div fit an empty space by using only CSS and flexbox,
but I can't find a way to make it work.

I can't change the HTML layout, and can't use absolute positioning either.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.start {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.right {
  order: 2;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.end {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left, .right, .end {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="start">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="end"></div>
</div>
```

what I'm trying to get is:

[image: expected result]

Is it achievable using only flexbox ?

Comment: Are the <div>s actually fixed height? Can you use css grid?

Comment: No, the height of the div is dynamic :/

Comment: By the way last <div> should be </div>

Comment: If you can remove div start it will be very easy with grid https://jsfiddle.net/bgxL45dy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve the desired result with the existing HTML code applying flex (the main problem is that the blocks are not at the same level HTML-wise), but you can use `float` left and right to do it:

```css
.left {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}

.end {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.left,
.right,
.end {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="start">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="end"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you are !

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%
}
.left {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.start {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.right {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.end {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="start"></div>
    <div class="end"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Please fully explain your answer. "Here you are!" doesn't tell anyone what you did

Comment: OP specifically said he can't change the HTML layout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).